# Match and Conditional Formatting from Matrix

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

Take a look at this matrix-scheme that I have:

[image]

This is like "base" which is populated with -1- and - _ - and where -1- represents not compatibility with some of these options.

On other sheet I got like dropdowns which is trying to find right match for many of these combinations, using:

```
=MATCH(A10;$T$14:$T$121;0) 
=MATCH(A10;$S$14:$BL$14;0)
```

So for horizontal and vertical match (first match is vertical and second horizontal), and then:

```
=OR(INDEX($S$14:$BO$119;B12;$B$13)="nk";INDEX($S$14:$BO$119;B12;$C$13)="nk";INDEX($S$14:$BO$119;B12;$D$13)="nk";INDEX($S$14:$BO$119;B12;$E$13)="nk";INDEX($S$14:$BO$119;B12;$F$13)="nk";INDEX($S$14:$BO$119;B12;$G$13)="nk";INDEX($S$14:$BO$119;B12;$H$13)="nk";INDEX($S$14:$BO$119;B12;$I$13)="nk")
```

..For true/false statement when something is compatible with something, so I can use it in conditional formatting.

Is there any other way to do this? So that I can adequate and 100% correct matches when I am selecting some of the options in drop downs?

Can you see now what is actually issue, grey boxes are my references (which changing on drop downs depend on the configuration) where I have to look into that matrix that I already updated, and in a case of a match, I should get some boolean value for conditional formatting, something like I did, but I am not sure if that is good way. 
I still used this:

```
=OR(INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$B$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$C$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$D$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$D$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$E$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$F$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$G$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$H$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$I$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$J$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$K$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$L$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$M$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$N$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$O$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$P$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$Q$14)="1";INDEX(_0359_matrix[#All];E16;$B$17)="1")
```

..suggested formula doesnt work as it should be. There are more combinations that should do together. Bit messy and hard to explain. 
[image]

**So 3rd attempt. It is just small part of the whole picture. Down in a drop down area (yellowish fields) you got different groups (model, sensors etc) and everytime I am changing some of them I should get position there where are 2´s (value of 2)in B14 and B15 so horizontal and vertical position which are taken from the main matrix area. This false/true boolean should be given anytime when there is a certain match -> true for ( 1 ) and false when ( _ ) and paralel change colors to red when I got ( 1 ) or true. The thing is as you can see there can be more matches in the same time lets say, for example some parts are not compatible with more than 1-2 parts and they have to simultaneously red! 
That is a reason I made this = or(index) in B16 function which is actually taking everything from matrix scheme, combining positions (B14 and B15) and giving me right answer.

I dont know if it is understandable now. Hopefully you got the point.**

[image]

Comment: Actually what is your issue? I mean there is always any other way to do something. What is wrong with INDEX and MATCH?

Comment: I still don't get what the question is. Can you explain it on a specific example in your screenshots? Like: Take value `VD1` from cell B12 match it with the row 1 in screenshot 1, then … and so on. Because your formulas are pretty useless to us if we don't know which cell is which. Checkout [mvce] if this helps you to give us a good example.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  Edited!!! Hopefully you got the point now....

Comment: Im stuck here already: *"B14 and B15 so horizontal and vertical position which are taken from the main matrix area"*. What is the "main matrix area"? You use names and therms that are non-standard in Excel and you don't introduce them before using. That makes it hard to understand. Is the main matrix area the one in picture 1? • Also where do the numbers in row 14/15 come from? And your pictures change row/column references everytime. Picture 2 row 15 has FALSE but in picture 3 row 15 has numbers. Which picture matches with the addresses in the formulas in your question?

Comment: Then you say *"The thing is as you can see there can be more matches in the same"* I don't even know what you try to match/find where? What is the value you search for? And wich is the data source you try to find that search_value? • Try not to show pictures where data rows magically move to another row, that makes it horrendous difficult to get what is going on. Use the row/column numbers in your text when referencing to some data. I don't know how to explain it better, but I cannot find in the pictures what you are talking about in the text.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ is there a way to make a new thread and deleting this? then I will write it bit more, now it is cut in slices and none can find what is about.

Comment: 2 possibilities either delet this one and start a complete new question, or use this one and the [edit] button. You can completely edit and change the content then. Upto you what you decide to do. But rephrasing it would be a good idea.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks man, will do the editing then soon. Thanks for the support till now.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I posted as a new thread but I see now I cant delete this post :/ sorry for spamming here.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you? The formula in the picture is

```
=OFFSET(A1,MATCH(I9,A:A,0)-1,MATCH(I8,1:1,0)-1)
           ---------------   ---------------
                  |                 |
                  V                 V
=OFFSET(A1,       5       -1,       3       -1)
```

wich means offset from A1 down 4 rows and right 2 colums which makes you end up in C5.

[image]

It matches the header row and the header column to get its number and then uses `Offset` to move from A1 these number of rows and columns to get the value in the grid.

Of course as MG92 pointed out, `INDEX` would be preferable as it is not volatile:

```
=INDEX(A1:E6,MATCH(I9,A:A,0),MATCH(I8,1:1,0))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `INDEX($A$1:$E$6,MATCH(I9,A:A,0),MATCH(I8,1:1,0))` give you the same result, without using offset, which is volatile?

Comment: @MG92 I felt indeed something was odd using Offset here. But actually the question was *"Is there any other way to do this?"* Problem is that the OPs question is already a bit strange and unclear. • But yes, you are right INDEX would be preferable.

Comment: @MG92  Hi, check edtited version...index match goes but not in this particular way.